# How do I make this paint match?

Tags: paint

I'm painting drywall. The paint I purchased was said (by the developer) to be the paint used on this wall. The paint however doesn't match as you can see in the picture. I'm just shaking the can, and then putting the paint on the wall with a brush. Is there a step I'm missing?

[image]

Comment: How long did you let it dry before taking the picture?

Comment: I allowed it to dry for days before taking the picture.

Comment: Maybe it is the lighting from the picture but it looks like the two paints are a different gloss.

Comment: thin the paint down only slightly, we recommend about 10% with water, assuming it's a latex based paint. Instead of filling your brush up, very lightly dip it in the paint and feather it in with smooth strokes. Doubt either of those will work, that is obviously a different color. As mentioned below, paint fades, but not like that.

Answer (score 2):

Paint fades.

It is extremely hard to get an exact match on any paint after a few months.  The best solution is to paint a whole section (try ending at the edge of a window or door) or even a whole wall.

An even better approach is to cut out a small patch of the now faded wall to be matched (you can patch and paint it later when you repaint) and take it in to the paint store for a computer scan match.

You still should paint a whole section as described above, but the joint will be even less noticable.